# ccavenue woocommerce plugin is not redirecting to ccavenue

Tags: woocommerce

I have an ecommerce site(woocommerce). Recently I had developed a theme by myself and had added required plugins including woocommerce. As woocommerce has not payment gateway option for ccavenue, I added another plugin ccavenue advanced and it provided ccavenue option in woocommerce. Earlier it used to work fine, before this new theme.

But now, when user try to pay, after entering billing details, when user click place order, instead of redirecting to ccavenue, a page with order details with a message appear,

"Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with CCAvenue."

But below there is no button. Please see the image
[This is the final page appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZFJK.png)

I have tried with other available ccavenue woocommerce plugin but the result is same. I have included woocommerce.php file also. but still same result. I tried with paypal and it is redirecting to paypal.

I searched over internet a lot but could not able to find out any solution.

Any guidance will be helpful. Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Hi did you solve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: This was css issue. Currently I am using my own developed CCAVENUE plugin and it is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your PHP version to latest one. The issue happened due to the disabled condition of Soapclient extension in older version php.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker